# Specify a Path control using behind code in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing

I am trying to draw an ellipse using the `Path` control dynamically.

In my `MainWindow()`:

```
EllipseGeometry ellipse = new EllipseGeometry(new Point(50, 50), 45, 20);

var path = new Path();
path.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
path.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;

path.Fill = Brushes.Black;
path.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
path.StrokeThickness = 2;
path.Data = ellipse;
```

but nothing shows up.

I realised that I need to "associate" the `path` object with my dialog box but I do not know how to do that. Is there a way to accomplish this via non-XAML methods since I will need to dynamically generate many different `path` objects?

Comment: Add it to the Children collection of a Panel in your window. That said, you should not create the Path element in code behind. Instead, declare it in XAML and bind its Path property to a property of type Geometry in your view model or in your window class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you are missing is basically that:

```
SamplePanel.Children.Add(path);
```

The above assumes that there is a Panel named SamplePanel in your window's XAML, e.g.

```
<Grid x:Name="SamplePanel" />
```